# What is the neighborhood of $\partial \mathbb{R}^n_+$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

What is the neighborhood of $\partial \mathbb{R}^n_+$ ? I was reading a theorem in a paper in which one of the assumptions is that $\mu(x)>0$ in a neighborhood of $\partial \mathbb{R}^n_+$.

I am not sure if I understand what this exactly means? For example in case of $\partial\mathbb{R}^2_+$ , would an open ball intersecting the the Y or the  X axes a neighborhood of $\partial\mathbb{R}^2_+$

Comment: Is $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ the set of points with every coordinate positive?

Comment: I don't quite understand your last question. Do you mean "would an open ball intersecting the $Y$ or the $X$ axes be a neighborhood of $\partial \mathbb{R}^2_+"?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I wanted to ask . Sorry for the imprecision

Answer (score 1):

Having $\mu(x)>0$ in a neighborhood of $\partial\mathbb{R}_+^n$ just means that $\mu(x)>0$ if you get "close enough" to points in $\partial\mathbb{R}_+^n$.

Formally, it means that you can take an open set around $\partial\mathbb{R}_+^n$ (notice that such neighborhood must contain $\partial\mathbb{R}_+^n$, not just intersect it) such that $\mu>0$ in that open set.

Equivalently, it means that you can take a ball around every point in $\partial\mathbb{R}_+^n$ such that $\mu>0$ in that ball.

So, for the case of $\partial\mathbb{R}_+^2$, around every point in those semi-axes ($X^+_0$ and $Y^+_0$), you have a ball in which $\mu>0$.

As for your last question, the answer is no. It would just be a neighborhood of any point in that intersection. A neighborhood of $\partial\mathbb{R}_+^2$ would have to contain this set, not just intersect it.

Comment: What does the boundary look like ?

Comment: Again, I'm assuming that $\mathbb{R}_+^n$ is the set of points with EVERY coordinate positive. Is that right?
If it is, in the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$, the boundary is the two $\textit{positive}$ axes and the origin. In $\mathbb{R}^3$, it's the origin, the positive axes, and the quarters of planes $$z=0\quad\text{with}\quad x,y>0$$ $$y=0\quad\text{with}\quad x,z>0$$ $$x=0\quad\text{with}\quad y,z>0$$
And so on. It gets hard to visualize but it's always the set delimitating the subset of all positive coordinates